# How can you efficiently store a huge javascript string to a file using php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a website which generates gifs, frame by frame using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [php](/questions/tagged/php). In short the process is:

1. **Generate** a frame (stored as a long base64 encoded string) using javascript
2. **Send** this string to `writeToFile.php`, which will open a partially copmlete file and add the string at the end of the file.
3. **Wait** for a success in writing to the file, then go to step 1 for the next frame

Thus, as the end, I'll have a created, piece by piece, a file that has all of the frames of the gif in order. Most of the time it works. However, sometimes, two frames get switched around, which makes the gif stutter (for example, when the ball hits the post in [this gif](http://fat.gfycat.com/DeadCourageousBichonfrise.gif)).

I'm piecing this together using calls to php, and waiting until they succeed. From my understanding of the ajax success event, the code *should* wait until the previous frame is done saving before generating the next frame, so **how is it possible that the php can write to the file out of order?**

I have tried setting async to false in the ajax request, but the stuttering still occurs (although less often). On top of that, generation is slower, so that is not my ideal solution.

#### Javascript

```
//Dostep - The first part of the frame generation. If we aren't done saving to file, wait 100 ms then check again
//This waits until the last frame is generated before generating a new one
var step=(function(){
    var doStep = function () {      
        if (frameSavingToFile){ //Check
            setTimeout(
                 function(){
                      doStep();
                  },
                   100 //if we are saving to file, wait
                 );  
                    return;
         }
        //there is code here I've omitted which moves to the next frame, and stores the string
        saveFrameToFile(frame);
    }
    return function () {
        if (!stepping) setTimeout(doStep, 0);
    };

}

function saveFrameToFile(theEncoder,isLastFrame){
    frameSavingToFile=1;
    var toAppend=window.btoa(theEncoder.stream().getData()); //add in the base 64 to the file
    //save it to a file, on success set frameSavingToFile to 0
    var toPassIn={'fileName':tmpFileName+".gif",'contents':toAppend};
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/writeToFile.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: toPassIn,
       success: function(results) {
           console.log(results);
           frameSavingToFile=0;//we are no longer saving to file
           if (isLastFrame){//this is set to 1 on the last frma
               generationComplete();//don't generate more frames, load the gif for viewing
               return;
           }
       }
    });


}
```

#### PHP - writeToFile.php

Opens the file, appends the frame's contents, and closes

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['contents'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$data = base64_decode($data);//puts it in a format I can store
$myfile = fopen('path/to/file/'.$fileName, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: how are the doStep() calls made?

Comment: I edited it to show how doStep is called. When generation is started, we call step once. I had left out the stepping aspect, as I've confirmed via console.log that the javascript is correctly stepping through the frames in order.

Comment: you're doing ajax, which is asynchronous. There is **NO** guarantee what order the individual requests will arrive at the server. That depends entirely on the network between the client and server. There's also no real guarantee what order the server will process the requests as they arrive.

Comment: Encoding, sending data, decoding, and opening a file for writing for every frame seems inefficient to begin with.  Why not just send it to PHP once it is finished with all the frames and check if writes correctly?

Comment: @Devon I had initially done that, and things were fine. However, bigger gif files had such long strings that they completely used up the memory of the browser, crashing it. I realize that sending larger chunks at a time would be more efficient, I agree. I'm trying to fix this issue prior to that one.

Comment: @MarcB I Is waiting until we get a success not sufficient in showing that the previous write is finished?

Comment: @jeffkillian, I assume the issue is with the encoding process then? The memory of the browser for a long string should be relatively the same as the length of the string, or the size of the GIF in other words.  I don't see any modern browsers crashing from that.

Comment: @jeffkillian: ah yeah, I missed the `frameSavingToFile` bit. so theoretically, yes, each subsequent write should wait for the previous one. however, a safer method (instead of using global sentinel variables) is to simply have your `success:` handler call the next write call itself. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a bit of a race condition with your timeout loop.

Comment: @Devon The issue with long strings was in the encoding, yes. It involves some appending and iterating, which slows down when you have strings of length 19,000,000.  I'm using a library for encoding, and was hoping to stay away from modifying it, especially if it can be solved with a simpler php fix.

Comment: @MarcB I'm familiar with race conditions, but am having trouble seeing the conditions. Can you elaborate exactly what the two conditions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code's overly complicated, with the timeout loop and whatnot. Why not simply have the ajax call's success handler re-call to start the next write?

e.g.

```
function savedata() {
    var toAppend=window.btoa(theEncoder.stream().getData()); //add in the base 64 to the file
    if (toAppend != '') { // or whatever it takes to see if the encoder's done
      $.ajax(
        blah blah blah,
        success: savedata // keep "looping" until there's nothing left to do
      );
    } else {
       console.log('done');
    }
}
```

This way you simply keeping firing out ajax requests until there's no more data to be saved, and everything simply "ends". You also guarantee that the next call doesn't go out until the previous one has completed. You'll also be saving up to ~99ms per call in NOT waiting for your timeout to finish.

Comment: It took some fiddling of functions, but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default ajax calls in jQuery are asynchronous. Meaning they get send simultaneously to the server. Try setting this flag in your `$.ajax({})` config object: `async: false`

This blocks the javascript execution until the request comes back from the server.

Comment: I had tried that and the stuttering still occurred (albeit less often), and generation was much slower. Also, would this run into issues if multiple people were trying to generate simultaneously, as everyone would have to wait on everyone else?

Comment: no this is only from your browser. In other words each client connected to the page can send their own synchronous requests to the server.

Comment: On a separate note, it's good to know that the asyncs from browsers are independent, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

your code does not wait,

> 3. Wait for a success in writing to the file, then go to step 1 for the next frame

try with synchronous request:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "php/writeToFile.php",
   type: "POST",
   async: false,
   data: ...
```

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active.

Comment: if you need efficiency you never should use 'async: false'

Comment: As I mentioned to think win win, I tried that, and it worked better, but not perfect. Of more importance, it generated a lot more slowly, so I'm hoping to avoid that method if at all possible. My true question revolves around why the way I'm doing it is failing.